# UITableViewCell: imageView resize in edit mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I subclassed `UITableViewCell` (subtitle style) and I have to set the imageView property runtime. The size of the image can be different for each cell, but I want the imageView to be squared (fixed size). For this reason I set at first a squared image as a placeholder. This is the code of the init method:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    // Other settings...

    [self.imageView.layer setCornerRadius:2.0f];
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [self.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];

    return self;
}
```

In the layoutSubviews method I just call the super method, while I set the image in the UITableViewController once I get it from its URL. This is working fine as you can see here:

[image: Working!]

But when I enter in edit mode something happens and I get this:

[image: Not working anymore]

I tried to set imageView frame in layoutSubviews method but the image is not aligned and textDetail label keep starting in the same position of the above screenshot... where am I wrong?

Comment: use a custom layout and not the default imageview of UITableViewCell

Comment: @Shubhank I hope there's a way to use a property that is exactly what I need. It doesn't make sense to replicate the same layout, I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: there are probably constraints set in default layout and that is why it can expand. it is recommended to use custom layout to control size of imageview